# need help to write a trigger

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have three tables:

Orders:
`orderid, valuedid, valuesdesc`

Customers:
`customerid, cutomdesc`

Groups:
`groupid, groupdesc`

`valueid` - id of a customer or a group

`valuesdesc` -  must filled with appropriate for inserted `valueid` description from `Customers` or `Groups` depend on what (customer or group) user selected in the client.

So, when client send an insert query for `Orders` it consists `orderid` for new order and `valuedid`. And on a client side I know what user selected: group or customer.

What I need: if a new row inserted in `Orders`, corresponding `valuesdesc` for `valuedid` from Customers or Groups inserted in `valuesdesc` column.

I have an idea to insert with new order record `valuesdesc` which would contain key - fake value to pick the right dictionary (customers or groups), but how to create that trigger I unfortunately don't know for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I must say this is a very uncommon design. When you are inserting a record into `Orders`, you use `valuesdesc` to hint at the table that `valueid` references. But as soon as `valuesdesc` gets filled by the trigger, `valueid` essentially loses any meaning. That is, you haven't reveal us you've got any other way to tell a reference to `Customers` from a reference to `Groups`. So, you could just as well drop `valueid` altogether and use `valuesdesc` to pass both the 'dictionary' hint and the reference within that table.

Other than that, because `valueid` can reference more than one table, you cannot use a [foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx) constraint on it.

Anyway, in your present design you could try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Orders_UpdateValuesdesc
ON Orders
FOR INSERT
AS
UPDATE o
SET valuesdesc = COALESCE(c.customdesc, g.groupdesc)
FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN inserted ON o.orderid = i.orderid
  LEFT JOIN Customers c ON i.valuesdesc = 'Customers'
    AND i.valueid = c.customerid
  LEFT JOIN Groups g ON i.valuesdesc = 'Groups'
    AND i.valueid = g.customerid
```

The strings `'Customers'` and `'Groups'` are meant as the dictionary specifiers. You replace them with the actual values.

The trigger uses LEFT JOIN to join both `Customers` and `Groups`, then fills `Orders.valuesdesc` with either `customdesc` or `groupdesc`, depending on which one is not null.

Comment: Thank you for example. Andriy, as I've understood you explanation valueid is redundant after we get valuedesc because it loses reference and key meaning? It has pushed me on correct thoughts. I'll try.

Comment: @johnny: Yes, that's right. `valueid` is meaningful when you know which table is meant, and that calls for another column. In your case `valuesdesc` performs as that 'another column' temporarily, then it gets its own destined value and--'bye-bye, valueid', and `valueid` has a stupid look with its meaningless reference.